# In Microsoft Bot Framework How can restrict the number of characters to a particular number?

Tags: c#, botframework

(EX: I want add give phone number in the text box so only 10 numbers has to added there. More than ten should not be allowed)

Comment: You can do server-side input validation of the message text, but limiting input fields on the client-side isn't a feature that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have access to the front end in a channel, you will have to validate server side as Nils said.  In this example I am using the RootDialog.cs but, you could also do it in the message controller if you wanted.  You could try something like this, but may need to do some sort of while loop to reprompt multiple times.

```
        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        if (activity.Text.Length > 10)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Please enter a valid phone number");
            //prompt again
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        else
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Adaptive cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards) could solve this issue - you need to respond with a card which has a text input. Just set up `maxLength` property in the card's markup explicitly. Below is an example of the markup you need:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "0.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "phone",
      "placeholder": "Enter a phone number",
      "speak": "Enter a phone number",
      "maxLength": 10
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Action.Submit data",
    }
  ]
}
```